# .htaccess URL rewrite rule stops working while logged in as admin Drupal 8

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, url-rewriting, drupal-8

I am currently hosting a Drupal 8 site on BlueHost in a subdirectory at `~/public_html/drupal` so the full url to the site by default is: 
`example.org/drupal/some-page-on-my-site`

Using BlueHost's references, I have setup my `.htaccess` in `~/public_html` to rewrite that URL to:
`example.org/some-page-on-my-site`

The issue is that I can't access `/admin` anymore without getting a 404 error and I can't access `/user` without getting:

```
Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default, use \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse for it.
```

If I am already logged in, the URL rewrite does not work and reverts the URL back to:
`example.org/drupal/some-page-on-my-site`

Basically, I want the URL to omit the `/drupal` subdirectory regardless of whether or not i'm logged into the site, something I haven't been having much luck finding an answer for yet.

Here is my `.htaccess` where `example.org` is my site URL and `drupal/` is the subdirectory it resides in:

```
# BlueHost.com
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.org/   [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^$ drupal/index.php    [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/example%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule .* drupal/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule .* example/index.php?q=$0 [QSA]
```

Note: BlueHost added all the `.well-known` conditions.

Comment: Cleared all caches (site and browser)?

Comment: Yeah. I did it again just to double check. Now I'm getting ```Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default, use \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse for it.``` when trying to access `/user`